# Google Drive SDK - client secret - how secret is it?

Tags: java, maven, oauth, google-drive-api, google-oauth

According to [the Google Drive SDK documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-java) you need to register your custom application with your Google account to obtain a `client-id` and `client-secret` information. You can then use these to build the link for your users to obtain access/refresh tokens.

According to some introductory guides on `oAuth` I've read, the client-secret information should be kept secretly in some cases and in some not. I'm building a Maven plugin in Java and it seems that you can hardly keep the value secret in this case.

Is it ok to release my code as open source including the client-secret information? Or does it mean a potential risk for me? And if it's not ok then how can I allow other people to use the plugin without disclosing the client-secret value?

Answer (score 3):

See Google's documentation on [OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp):

> The Google OAuth 2.0 endpoint supports applications that are installed on a device (e.g. Mobile, Mac, PC). These applications are distributed to individual machines, and it is assumed that these applications cannot keep secrets.

You should be fine releasing the secret. The only risk is that some rogue user "burns up" all your quota. [Per-user quotas](https://developers.google.com/console/help/#cappingusage) may help mitigate this issue if it arises.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you’re releasing. If you’re making a library that other people are going to use to build apps then no, they should register & use their own client secrets for their own apps.

If you have an app that you’re releasing and also want to post the source code because you're a good citizen, I’d also leave the client secret out of the posted source code; people who want their own versions of the apps should register their own clients.

Of course, anything that's compiled into a mobile app isn't really much of a secret any more, because mobile devices can't keep secrets.

Comment: It's the second case. Do you suggest that I omit the secret in the released source code but include it in the distributed JAR file? I fear that people would reverse engineer the secret from the JAR file. Requiring each user to register their own application at Google does not seem right either, though.

Comment: There's no point trying to hide it in the JAR, as you say, if you’re going to ship it you might as well ship it in the source.  I think that if other people build their own apps they should register their own apps as a general principle, that’s how OAuth is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Release the code without the tokens and explain how those using your code can get their own.
Otherwise people might abuse yours or copy them for other projects.
Otherwise you can burn your quotas and also if it gets copied into other apps, those will appear as yours ehen the permission dialog pops up to the user (with your app name and logo)

Comment: That seems like a good advice for "how to release the code" part of the question, but how about distributing the JAR file (uploading it to the Maven repository) so that people could use the plugin? As far as I know they could open the JAR file, reverse-engineer the classes and read the secret token. How do I prevent them from doing this?

Comment: Do you suggest that I should require ordinary users (every one of them) to register their own application at Google Drive and provide the client-id and client-secret values to the plugin as arguments? That seems like a safe but cumbersome way.

Comment: I thought you were keeping the secret on a server. For installed apps the oauth flow is different and doesnt use secrets. If you must use them I doubt anyone would go through the trouble of extracting them since its free to create your own (unless its a paid console project so you get more quotas). What I am refering is people copy/pasting from your published code without realizing it and using it for their own apps.